# Action on google Android o

Tags: android-tv, google-assistant-sdk

I have made it work well in my Raspberry pi3 with Android things. I can easily do a action with google assistant using Action SDK. (deploying a action.json file)

But now I am working on android-TV the version Android o(8.0). I login in the same google account, I can passe the voice to the google assistant in The decoder TV, but I don't know how to do some action as before. I read the documentation but I am so fuzz about how to make it work. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to invoke your action in the same way, by saying "talk to *action name*"

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work in my Android-TV. I find some files in my source code (150G) named AssistantVoiceInteractionService, I don't know if it is the files I should work with. My assistant is named katniss.apk.  I really need to find the way how to interact with it.  Any idea?                                                                                                       By the way I didn't invoke my action by saying "talk to action name", instead I invoked by simply saying the trigger phrase.

Comment: What trigger phrase?

Comment: "trigger": {
                "queryPatterns": [
                    "blink ($Speed:speed)? $SchemaOrg_Number:number times"    }                                                                                                                   This is a example for the part of  trigger I was using in my action.json file. in the links below, we find the section solution for partners, is this the part I should look at? My assistant prebuilt in my Android TV allow me to open a "Youtube video" But what I want is to customize my own google action(like turn the light on).

Comment: Okay, you're trying to deploy custom device actions for a device using the Assistant SDK. However, that is not possible as you do not own the Assistant implementation on your television. This is not related to Actions on Google.

Comment: (https://www.android.com/tv/)                                                                 From this link, we can see it's possible to do home control with google assistant built in Android Tv. Actually, we have the code source. Do you have some suggestions how to explore this feature. I have found some docs in this link  (https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable) they talk about how to use search API

Comment: If you want to do home control, you need to do it through the [smart home feature](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). The capabilities of smart home are built into the Assistant, so you would not need to use custom device actions (and you cannot use custom device actions on a device that you don't own, like Android TV)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Actually, We do own the Android TV. currently, I am working in a company to developer the new generation of Android TV decoder. We have the google as partner. Google just give us the assistant.apk (we don't have the source code of assistant, but we have other source code ) . Do you think it's possible to do home control? and should I use smart home feature?

Comment: You should look into the smart home feature.

Comment: It works! it works as a app links to my google account. You are the best!

Comment: Hi Nick I have successfully create a app with dialog flow. In this app I can do a conversation with google assistant integrated in our Android TV. As you said I have looked into smart home feature, But I still have no idea how to report some sensors state or turn on the light in the home.  Can you give me some more suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're building your own smart home devices, you connect from your smart home service to the devices to send commands. If you're just using the Assistant, the user can just control their own devices.

Comment: Hi, I want to make a recapture to make it clear :)
I have made a demo with Raspberry pi3 and Android things. This demo use Action SDK. When the user trigger google assistant with a trigger phrase, google assistant response with a custom phrase and in this method :
@Override
public void onDeviceAction(String intentName, JSONObject parameters)   {...}I get a intent callback with its identification. So, I can do my own action in this method like using a GPIO to turn on a led or Sending MQTT message to my sensor.

Comment: The idea is to make the same demo with Android TV. Until now, I can use dialogflow to make a app, user can easily make a conversation with Android TV. but my use case is : user says turning on the light and google assistant integrated in Android TV will response "ok, I will turn on the light". And I will get a return callback in my Android TV source code. In this section of code, I can do my own action (like using gpio to turn on the light...)
Thank you for your help!

Comment: You'd need to register with smart home to control a light on TV. There's not a way to add device actions to the Assistant on that surface.